# В какой памяти хранятся указатели C++?

Tags: c++, указатели

В какой памяти хранятся указатели? Именно указатель, а не переменная, на которую мы указываем. Например, создали мы указатель `int* a`; и вот теперь задача - а где он хранится, я думаю, что в стеке, но может я не прав.

Comment: Там же где и любое другое значение (почти любое): в регистре, или в стеке, или в куче.

Comment: Зависит от того где вы их определяете

Comment: А какая разница, где он хранится?

Comment: В С++ тип объекта не определяет то, где он хранится. Также указатели не указывают на переменные, они указывают на объекты.

Comment: Когда просто в теле функции вы пишете `int *p;`, то вы правильно думаете, такая переменная (ее тип указатель на int) будет храниться в стеке (если оптимизатор не выбросит ее вообще, но это уже совсем другая история)

Answer (score 1):

В том же месте, где хранился бы не указатель. Потому что указатели - это подвид переменных (точнее, объектов), а не что-то отличное от них.

Answer (score 1):

Где выделите, там и будет, ведь указатель -  просто адрес (число), просто у него особая сематика.

Например:

```
auto ptr = new Something;
```

Тут указатель будет хранится на стеке, а в

```
auto ptr2ptr = new Something*;
```

Указатель на объект (**на самом деле на неопределенные данные, т.к. адрес объекта не присвоен!**) будет хранится в куче.

При этом `ptr2ptr` будет иметь тип `Something**`, т. е. будет указателем на указатель, который хранится в куче, а сам будет выделен на стеке.